# want to find when the job will be started in celery

Tags: celery, celery-task, celerybeat

i am new to `celery`. i have some configuration in `celeryconfig.py` as follow:

```
from datetime import timedelta

BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND="redis"
CELERY_REDIS_HOST="localhost"
CELERY_REDIS_PORT=6379
CELERY_REDIS_DB=0
CELERY_IMPORT=("mail")

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE={'runs-every-30-seconds' :
                        {
                                'task': 'mail.mail',
                                'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
                        },
                    }
```

i have scheduled that the job will run periodically in 30 seconds. now i want that the jobs should start on `29 aug` at `4:00PM` then how should i configure this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Cron instead of timedelta. The Celery documentation discusses this specifically, and provides some useful examples. See [Crontab schedules](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Here is an example from Celery:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 A.M
    'every-monday-morning': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week=1),
        'args': (16, 16),
    },
}
```

To make this work for your condition, you will also need to specify the cron `month_of_year` parameter.

Comment: hey, i want that the job should start at a fix time and should repeat after every 30 secons

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. Off the top of my head, I can't think of a simple way to do this using the CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE setting. However, this can be accomplished by creating a custom beat schedule class. See 'Custom Scheduler Class' http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html and here is the actual beat scheduler class documentation http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/reference/celery.beat.html#celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
You will probably want to create a task that adds a new entry into the schedule, where that entry will be the 30-sec task

Comment: hey for example i have a job which i want to start at 4:00 PM on 31-Aug-2012 and this job should run after every 15 minutes